# Why won't JQuery Mobile toolbar appear

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a mobile version of my site using JQuery Mobile.  I'd like a fixed header toolbar and a fixed footer toolbar to appear on all pages.  However, those portions of the page are instead being written out as simple HTML lists.  Here is the relevant header code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

            <title>Nightscape Creations Wallpapers</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/NCMobile.min.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        </head>

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</a>
            <h1>Nightscape Creations</h1>
            <a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-theme="a">Home</a>

            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#liveWallpapers">Live Wallpapers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#staticWallpapers">Static Wallpapers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This code is visible at www.NightscapeCreations.com on the mobile site.

It seems like the JQuery code is either not being included correctly or is not being initialized.  I'm not sure if maybe I missed something obvious in the installation that I just need a second set of eyes on.

If it's relevant, the remainder of the page might be similar to:

```
    <body>  
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            Some text
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="liveWallpapers">
            Some text
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="products">
            Some text
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="about">
            Some text
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="staticWallpapers">
            Some text
        </div>
    </body>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>All images, animations, and content © Nightscape Creations</h1>
        <a href="setSessionVar.cfm?varName=browserType&varValue=desktop&goto=home.cfm">Visit Desktop Site</a>
    </div>
</html>
```

**EDIT 1**

Per a suggestion by mwfire I have moved all of my visible code inside of the body tags.  A simplified version of the page is now available with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nightscape Creations Wallpapers</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/NCMobile.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>




    <body>

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">Back</a>
            <h1>Nightscape Creations</h1>
            <a href="#home" data-icon="home" data-theme="a">Home</a>

            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#liveWallpapers">Live Wallpapers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#staticWallpapers">Static Wallpapers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>



<div data-role="page" id="home1">


<div style="font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;">Welcome</div>
Welcome to Nightscape Creations Mobile.  Here you will find animated live wallpapers, static wallpapers, and links to physical products
with the wallpaper images included.  Use the header button above to browse the mobile site, or
<a href="setSessionVar.cfm?varName=browserType&varValue=desktop&goto=home.cfm">click here</a> to visit the main site instead.



</div>



        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>All images, animations, and content © Nightscape Creations</h1>
            <a href="setSessionVar.cfm?varName=browserType&varValue=desktop&goto=home.cfm">Visit Desktop Site</a> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, this does not cause the toolbars to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually all your HTML code belongs inside the **body** tag. I bet you don't see any footer as well ;)

**Edit**
Just to clarify, the structure is supposed to be like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE ...>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <!-- All visible HTML content goes here! -->
  </body>
</html>
```

No HTML tags should be outside the body tag (except head, body & Doctype).

You can find more on page structures [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/page-structure).

**Edit2**
In addition to this, header and footer are supposed to be inside the data-role="page" div. jQuery displays one page at a time, think of it as a single HTML page. It has to include the complete structure of a single page (if you want header and footer, of course), like:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
       <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        Content
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
         <h3>Footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, good catch!  That totally slipped by me.  Unfortunately, this does not resolve the issue.  I've updated the live code and will update the question above momentarily.  Would you happen to have any other thoughts?

Comment: Ah, I completely misunderstood how the JQuery Mobile structure works.  Thanks for the update.  I'll give this a try tonight and report back.  :)

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks so much!